# TikZ: What affects the space between nodes placed with `below of=` syntax?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How does TikZ decide how much space to put between these two nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node [below of=a] (b) {B};
  \draw (a.north west) rectangle (a.south east);
  \draw (b.north west) rectangle (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And how can I change it? I've added some rectangles to illustrate the extent of the nodes.

I can, of course, have more control as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node at (a.south) [anchor=north] (b) {B};
  \draw (a.north west) rectangle (a.south east);
  \draw (b.north west) rectangle (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And then just add whatever space I want to `(a.south)` but this is less semantic and much more fiddly.

There must be a way to globally change the space between nodes placed with the `positioning` library...

To clarify, I'd ideally like to specify *the separation between node* rather than the distance between node centres. This is because I have nodes of varying y-height and I'd like to have them have a uniform distance *between* them.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are loading the `positioning` library but then use `below of=...`,
however the library provides the syntax `below=<optional length> of ...`, while
`below of` is already provided by the TikZ core.

Try something like this instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node [below=1cm of a] (b) {B};
  \draw (a.north west) rectangle (a.south east);
  \draw (b.north west) rectangle (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha. And this specifies distance between nodes rather than distance between node centres. Excellent!

Comment: How to make the top edge of node `b` coincides with bottom edge of node `a`? I mean, I want zero distance between the nodes so that if they are color filled we can not see any white space between them.

Answer (score 12):

Here is something you may use: the `\tikzset` command and the `node distance` option. Note that I drew the rectangles by specifying the node shape and telling tikz to draw the shape.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{my node/.style={node distance=1cm,shape=rectangle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw=red,my node] (a) {A};
  \node[draw=blue,my node,below=of a] (b) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You may also specify the node distance at the beginning of a picture or a particular node : `\tikzpicture[node distance=1cm]` or `\node[node distance=1cm]`

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way to draw round a node! `node distance` is the distance between the centres of the nodes. Is there a way to specify the _separation_ between nodes? That is, the distance between, say `a.south` and `b.north`?

Comment: You can adjust this with `inner sep` and `outer sep` (the space added within and outside the border, respectively) or by setting a `minimum width` or `minimum height`, depending on the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is in the manual : 16.5.3 Advanced Placement Options (CVS version of pgfmanual but I think you can find this paragraph in the classic manual).

The example gives in the manual is : ((see Martin's answer)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,
  positioning
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw,scale=2]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
  \node (some node) at (1,1) {some node};
  \node (other node) [above=1cm of some node] {\tiny above=1cm of some node};
  \draw [<->] (some node.north) -- (other node.south)
                                node [midway,right,draw=none] {1cm};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Important :

> When this library is loaded, the options like above or above left
>   behave differently. With the positioning library loaded, the above
>   option does not take a simple ⟨dimension⟩ as its parameter. Rather, it
>   can (also) take a more elaborate ⟨specification⟩ as parameter. This
>   ⟨specification⟩ has the following general form: It starts with an
>   optional ⟨shifting part⟩ and is followed by an optional ⟨of-part⟩.

Remark :
 You can  instead use the distance between the nodes, use the distances between the centers : You need to do this use the option `on grid`. The manual gives

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3);
  %  Not gridded
  \node (a1) at (0,0) {not gridded};
  \node (b1) [above=1cm of a1] {fooy};
  \node (c1) [above=1cm of b1] {a};
  %  gridded
  \node (a2) at (2,0) {gridded};
  \node (b2) [on grid,above=1cm of a2] {fooy};
  \node (c2) [on grid,above=1cm of b2] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But another possibility is to use `node distance` (see Frederic's answer).
The syntax is different `above=of ...`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw,node distance=5mm]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3);
  %  Not gridded
  \node (a1) at (0,0) {not gridded};
  \node (b1) [above=of a1] {fooy};
  \node (c1) [above=of b1] {a};
  %  gridded
  \begin{scope}[on grid]
    \node (a2) at (2,0) {gridded};
    \node (b2) [above=of a2] {fooy};
    \node (c2) [above=of b2] {a};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Last remark:
 I don't like `positioning` the first argument : I use Tikz from the first version and  `positioning` redefines some options. The second argument is : it's not easy to scale a picture that uses `positioning` and `node distance`.