# Position two stacked tikz matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I would like to take two `TikZ` `matrix`, possibly of different dimensions and stack them. My demo code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\
};
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
1   & 3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There should be some space between the matrices and they should be aligned. I've tried to use `below of` but it doesn't seem to work...

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use a `scope` and shift the entire content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\
};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
1   & 3 \\
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make this work if the column styles include `anchor=base west`? If one scoped node is wider than the other scoped nodes, the aligned positions are different.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander It is possible by choosing proper shift distances and anchors. It is hard to say without some code though.

Answer (score 11):

A `matrix` is just really a `node`, so if you name the top matrix `(Top)` then you can use `below of=Top` in the other matrix to position it:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix  [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}] (Top)
{
0   & 6 \\
};
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}, below of=Top]
{
1   & 3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happened to good ol' `at (3,2)`? :P

Comment: As I pointed out, I tried to use below of and it doesn't work. The matrices actually overlap.

Comment: @JonSlaughter: Is that comment directed at me or percusse? If so, and this solution does not work for you, it would be helpful if you posted a more realistic example

Comment: @JonSlaughter As Peter showed it works without any complication. What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: Well, the example is more complex. Why it doesn't work I have no idea. Harish's method worked so I'll go with that. I don't like necessarily hard coding the offset but it will do. My matricies are just normal matrices not much different than above except they use math nodes.

Comment: Ok, I guess that shows how important it is to set up the MWE as realistic as possible.  Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @JonSlaughter If you look at the error that TikZ gives then you know why. manual shift would be very difficult as the examples get more complex. Also you can use the `label` option instead of using a matrix.

Comment: Hey, I think that [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25681/tikz-what-affects-the-space-between-nodes-placed-with-below-of-syntax) gets to the problem with using `below of`, and solves it pretty well.

Comment: Doesn't solve my issue with multiple widths and inconsistent left alignment, though :/

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: Difficult to help without more detail. I would recommend that you post a new question, with a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.