# Maintaining alignment between irregularly vertically spaced TikZ matrix nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, horizontal-alignment, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to create a diagram with pairs of rectangles of different sizes, each separated by a fixed interval. Additionally, I want each pair to be left-aligned at the same point. Here's an example from my current draft in QTikZ:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \tikzstyle{ann} = [draw=none,fill=none,right]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 1};\\
    \node (1) [rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\

    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 2};\\
    \node[rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\

    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Content Delivery};\\
    \node[rectangle] {This one is much longer -- Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic of example without spacing]

This one doesn't have the spacing between each pair that I'm looking for, though. Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83046/position-two-stacked-tikz-matrices/83049) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25681/tikz-what-affects-the-space-between-nodes-placed-with-below-of-syntax), I tried three different methods for adding that spacing, but always ended up with something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{ann} = [draw=none,fill=none,right]

    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 1};\\
    \node (1) [rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 2};\\
    \node[rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Content Delivery};\\
    \node[rectangle] {This one is much longer -- Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: graph with spacing problems]

How do I get the alignments to stay consistent while keeping this heterogeneous spacing?

Comment: Can we wrap the last cell?

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't be horrible. Would that involve setting a fixed max. width for all nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the anchor for the scope itself.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

    \tikzset{ann/.style = {draw=none,fill=none,right}}
    \begin{scope}[anchor=west]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 1};\\
    \node (1) [rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm,anchor=west]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 2};\\
    \node[rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,anchor=west]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Content Delivery};\\
    \node[rectangle] {This one is much longer -- Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, don't use `tikzstyle` which is deprecated. Use `\tikzset` instead.

Comment: both answers were very helpful for a newbie :) I flipped a coin to choose which to accept.

Answer (score 5):

Specifying a `text width` seems to do the job:

[image]

or you can use the `matrix anchor=west`:

[image]

### Code: `text width=`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,text width=9cm]

    \tikzstyle{ann} = [draw=none,fill=none,right]

    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 1};\\
    \node (1) [rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 2};\\
    \node[rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Content Delivery};\\
    \node[rectangle] {This one is much longer -- Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `matrix anchor=`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, matrix anchor=west]

    \tikzstyle{ann} = [draw=none,fill=none,right]

    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 1};\\
    \node (1) [rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west},
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Category 2};\\
    \node[rectangle] {Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=blue!20,},column 1/.style={anchor=base west}, text width=6cm,
        row sep=0.0cm,column sep=0.5cm]  {
    \node[rectangle,fill=green] {Content Delivery};\\
    \node[rectangle] {This one is much longer -- Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti};\\
    };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good. Is there a way to avoid forcing all nodes to have the same fixed width?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: Use the text width for all longer nodes alone (instead of `tikzpicture`) like: `\node[rectangle,text width=4in] {This one is much longer...`

Answer (score 1):

Using a `matrix` to align all nodes is a good solution, but you don't need to divide all the blocks between different matrices (or scopes) to force certain separations between rows. Next text (from pgfmanual) explains an easier solution

> The row-end command \\ allows you to provide an optional argument,
>   which must be a dimension. This dimension will be added to the list in
>   row sep. This means that, firstly, any numbers you list in this
>   argument will be added as an extra row separation between the line
>   being ended and the next line [...]

This means that although `\\` starts a new rows with `row sep` from previous row, `\\[1cm]` starts a new row with `row sep+1cm` separation from previous one. You can use this option every second row to obtain a certain distance between titled blocks.

Next code uses this solution to provide different distances between rows. It also uses a `\matrix of nodes` (load `matrix` library) which saves some typing. And last node shows you how to change `node options` for a particular one.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,   
    title/.style={rectangle,fill=green,draw,anchor=west,},
    block/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!20,draw,thick,anchor=west,text width=\linewidth}
]

    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
             every odd row/.style={nodes={title}},
             every even row/.style={nodes={block}},
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth]  {
    Category 1\\
    Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti\\[1cm]
    Category 2\\
    Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti\\[1cm]
    Content Delivery\\
    |[text width=.75\linewidth]|This one is much longer -- Lorem ipsum stuff in a wider text box like gibberish, copypasta, limericks, and bathroom graffiti\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! This is definitely easier to remember and use in the long run.