# Position two matrices vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-matrix

I want to show two 12x12 matrices side by side. This is a transition, so there should be an arrow *in the middle* between them. I have to use `tikz`, because i want to highlight the one entry that changed in this transition.

My question: is there a *nice* way to position this two matrices side by side with the arrow in the midle, that does *not* require a nasty try-and-error procedure with $\quad$ and other absolute spacing parameters? (all I've found so far is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83046/position-two-stacked-tikz-matrices), and they've used absolute spacing too).

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\mybox}[3]{
    \draw[color=red] (#1-#2-#3.north west) -- (#1-#2-#3.north east)--(#1-#2-#3.south east) -- (#1-#2-#3.south west)-- (#1-#2-#3.north west);
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{m}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    $\longrightarrow$
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(n)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{n}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Just the arrow}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{m}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    $\quad \qquad\longrightarrow\,$
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(n)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{n}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{nasty fix with absolut spaces}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the output: [image]

Comment: You should not be placing them in subfigures, if you intend to link the two as a single "image"

Comment: I wanted the opportunity to give them own captions in the "real" document, it's not that important though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\subcaptionbox`, if you want to have subcaptions, or nothing at all.

I declared `\small` in order to fit the big matrices in the page, it may be unnecessary for your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mybox}[3]{
    \draw[color=red] (#1-#2-#3.north west) -- (#1-#2-#3.north east)--(#1-#2-#3.south east) -- (#1-#2-#3.south west)-- (#1-#2-#3.north west);
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering\small
\subcaptionbox{Start}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{m}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}
    \raisebox{6.5\baselineskip}{$\longrightarrow$}
\subcaptionbox{End}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        \matrix(n)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{n}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}
    \caption{Just the arrow}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering\small
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{m}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \raisebox{6.5\baselineskip}{$\longrightarrow$}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        \matrix(n)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
        {
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&1 \\ 
            0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \&0 \\ 
            0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
            1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \&0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{n}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Just the arrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the matrices are wider than the specified with of the `subfigure` environment (`.4\textwidth`), so they stick out of the right edge. This causes the overlap with the arrow.

Reduce the size of the matrices, by modifying (a combination of), font size and `inner sep` for the nodes, and `column sep`, `row sep` for the matrix. I also increased the width of the `subfigure`s a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\mybox}[3]{
    \draw[color=red] (#1-#2-#3.north west) -- (#1-#2-#3.north east)--(#1-#2-#3.south east) -- (#1-#2-#3.south west)-- (#1-#2-#3.north west);
}
\tikzset{pmatrix/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,outer sep=0pt,
    nodes={
%     font={\small}, 
     inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,
    left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(m)[pmatrix]
        {
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{m}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    $\longrightarrow$
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(n)[pmatrix]
        {
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
        };
        \mybox{n}{10}{8}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Just the arrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something, but you don't need TikZ for that: a simple `\fcolorbox` will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}
\usepackage{xcolor}

 \begin{document}

    \[
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \mathclap{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\,1\,}} & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \
        \end{pmatrix}
   \longrightarrow
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \mathclap{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\,0\,}} & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
            1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0
            \end{pmatrix}
            \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no particular need for tikz. But the spacing in this solution does not fulfill my styling fetish...

Comment: Which spacing do you mean?

Comment: mathclap has fixed this i think, nice alternative, i like this!