# Can LaTeX place text by mm coordinates?

Tags: coordinates

My system generates LaTex letters and templates; however, my client has to fill out pre-built forms that they have no control over. I'd like to fill out these forms by measuring the coordinates in mm and then placing text using those coordinates in mm as the starting point. I can then print directly on top of the existing paper forms.

Ideally I'd like the LaTeX to function something like below:

```
\command{x coordinate}{y coordinate}{text1}\\
\command{x coordinate}{y coordinate}{text2}\\
\command{x coordinate}{y coordinate}{text3}\\
\command{x coordinate}{y coordinate}{text4}\\
\command{x coordinate}{y coordinate}{text5}\\
\command{x coordinate}{y coordinate}{text6}\\
```

In the event the customer form changes I can just change the coordinates. Is this approach possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108374/how-can-i-construct-a-page-layout-with-framed-boxes/108391#108391

Comment: May be useful/duplicate: [Using LaTeX for pre-printed paper](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162194)

Comment: Have you considered `textpos`?

Comment: Same question, other answer: [Using LaTeX for pre-printed paper](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162162)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One option using TikZ. All distances are measured from the upper left corner of the paper (this can be easily modified to choose another origin point):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\PlaceText[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] 
  at ([xshift=#1,yshift=-#2]current page.north west) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\PlaceText{20mm}{30mm}{First text}
\PlaceText{50mm}{30mm}{Second text}
\PlaceText{60mm}{70mm}{Third text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

With `textpos`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\newcommand\PlaceText[3]{%
\begin{textblock*}{10in}(#1,#2)  %% change width of box from 10in as you wish
#3
\end{textblock*}
}%
\textblockorigin{-5mm}{0mm}   %% Default origin top left corner and it can be changed in this line
\begin{document}
\PlaceText{0mm}{0mm}{Origin}
\PlaceText{20mm}{30mm}{First text}
\PlaceText{50mm}{30mm}{Second text}
\PlaceText{60mm}{70mm}{Third text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the two answers I received. It is very helpful.