# Writing a form-style table

Tags: pdftex, nicematrix, tablet

I would like to print the following table in latex:[image]

Any hint is wellcome!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152079/fill-in-boxes-for-forms-in-tikz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\sffamily
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{38}{wc{3mm}}}
\Block[l]{1-10}{Nom} \\
\Block[hvlines]{1-38}{} 
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \\
\rule{0pt}{15pt}
\Block[l]{1-10}{Address} \\
\Block[hvlines]{1-38}{} \\
\rule{0pt}{15pt}
\Block[l]{1-10}{Complement} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block[l]{1-10}{Bairro}\\
\Block[hvlines]{1-15}{} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block[hvlines]{1-22}{} \\
\rule{0pt}{15pt}
\Block[l]{1-10}{Town} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block{1-2}{State} &&& \Block[l]{1-8}{CEP} \\
\Block[hvlines]{1-25}{} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  \Block[hvlines]{1-2}{} &&& \Block[hvlines]{1-9}{} \\
\rule{0pt}{15pt}
\Block[l]{1-10}{Email} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block{1-2}{DOC} &&& \Block[l]{1-8}{Telephon} \\
\Block[draw]{1-24}{} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block[hvlines]{1-2}{} &&& \Block[hvlines]{1-10}{} \\
\rule{0pt}{15pt}
\Block[l]{1-10}{Email} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block{1-2}{DOC} &&& \Block[l]{1-8}{Telephon (other)} \\
\Block[draw]{1-24}{} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \Block[hvlines]{1-2}{} &&& \Block[hvlines]{1-10}{} \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I really thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is by no means the answer I'm only just starting myself, but it might get you on the right track.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Name\\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

SecondItem\\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I said new to all this I dont know why but there should be \\ after the titles and it didn't paste properly